# nodejs udp receive and reply on the same pc

Tags: node.js

I have a problem establishing a communication between two pieces of software.

The main software sends an udp packet to all the network, and I would like to answer with a simple nodejs application.

In my case the main.js is:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

const http = require("http");

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 12345;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(`{"message": "This is a JSON response"}`);
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});

socket.on('listening', function () {
    const address = socket.address();
    console.log('UDP socket listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

socket.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log('SERVER RECEIVED:', remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
    const response = "{\"AlpacaPort\":12345}";
    socket.send(response, 0, response.length, remote.port, remote.address);
    
});

socket.bind('32227');
```

But I have some problems:

The software sends a message from port 32227, but when I print the messages received, I found this:

[image]

The port is never the configured one, why?

If I try to force the answer to port 32227 it became a loop:

```
socket.send(response, 0, response.length, 32227, remote.address);
```

I had the same problem trying to make the same software with C#, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

On a TCP or UDP connection, there are always two ports: the port on the sending end and the port on the receiving end.

In your example, the receiving end is listening on port 32227. When the sender sends an UDP packet, it will do so on some randomly assigned free port. The message will then be sent from that port to the receiving port 32227.

For example: The sender opens port 58326 to send a message, and sends it to port 32227 on the server.

What you are printing on the server side is the remote port, which is the port that the sender used to send its message (for example 58326).

> I had the same problem trying to make the same software with C#, what am I missing?

What you're missing is how ports work with TCP/IP or UDP/IP networking; it has nothing directly to do with the programming language you are using.

Comment: Yes, I realize now that if I reply to 32227 I will auto respond to me, and I will send a new message to me and I will send another message to me etc etc..problably the problem is in the way how the other software try to resolve my http addres, or how I give him

Comment: the thing that I don't uderstand is why I cannot be 'localhost' but I need to use a fake domain or 127.0.0.1